# Order of parties when using "__ Introduction to __"

Tags: syntactic-analysis

When writing that *blank* is being introduced to *blank,* is there a formal rule for which party is supposed to be placed before "introduction to" and which party is placed after? In this instance, this statement is being used as the title of a presentation.

For example, if a client is visiting a company with which they are interested in working, is example one or example two more grammatically correct:
     (1) Client Introduction to Company
     OR
     (2) Company Introduction to Client

I am leaning towards example one, but I would love to know if/why that is incorrect.

Comment: It all depends on the context. Both are correct, depending on who is being introduced and who is being introduced to. Typically, both actions are made when the two subjects are people; The client and employee are introduced to each other. I'm not sure if you can introduce a business entity to a person, though :)

Comment: To reviewers: although at first glance it looks like a question on etiquette, the OP is actually asking about how to phrase "the title of a presentation".

Comment: @Brekt Whose client are they? Companies don't usually prepare presentations to poach the staff of their clients, so I assume the speaker speaks for a recruitment agency. Both options look awkward to me. If you're presenting an information pack to the prospective employee, it would probably be headed something like "Introduction to Stack Exchange". If you're presenting the candidate to the company, the title might consist of just the candidate's name and perhaps the position they applied for.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because experts in English aren't in a position to answer social questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a question of etiquette, rather than English.

This Emily Post Institute webpage provides the etiquette of [making introductions](http://emilypost.com/advice/making-introductions/).

They provide a general rule:

> It all boils down to **speaking to the person you wish to honor first**. For example, you’d like to introduce your college roommate to your grandmother.

It has a section for Business Introductions.

> FIRST: A client… THEN: Anyone in your company, including your CEO
>
> FIRST: Your boss, or a higher-up… THEN: A person of lower rank in the company

In the case cited, the introduction would be "Jim Client, may I present John Bigwig, the CEO of Big Corp."

Answer (score 0):

@Hank is right in the comments. It depends on the context. In situation (1), the client is being introduced to the company. In situation (2), the company is being introduced to the client. While these mean the exact same thing, the emphasis on the subjects has changed.

Imagine that one subject is unmoving, while the other moves. In situation (1), the client goes to the company to introduce himself. In situation (2), the company goes to the client to introduce itself. Obviously, actual physical movement is irrelevant, but it helps to visualize.

It is a matter of who you want to emphasize as the “moving” party. If I were the company, I may want to suggest that we’re reaching out to the client, even if the client comes to our office, so I would use situation (2). In your example, the client is interested in working with the company, so may use situation (1) to show that the client is reaching out.

Comment: I don’t think they mean the exact same thing.  If the client is being introduced to the company then the information flow is from company to client- the meeting is mainly to tell the client about the company.  If the company is being introduced to the client the information flow is from the client to the company- the meeting is mainly for the company to learn about the client. Although some information will likely also flow the other way, it is not the main purpose of meeting.